# how to validate particular format using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to allow number only in following format and check validation using javascript.

BEnnnn.nnn.nnn (where n is a number)

How can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions.

Comment: You can use Regex. Show us how far you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited for a full example :

BEnnnn.nnn.nnn => where `n` is `number`, then :

```
var testString = 'BE5555.333.333';
var pattern = new RegExp('^BE\\d{4}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}$','gm');
alert(pattern.test(testString));
```

or

```
var testString = 'BE5555.333.333';
var pattern = /^BE\d{4}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$/gm;
alert(pattern.test(testString));
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/rvHtr/

Recommended lecture BTW :

[Regex in a nutshell](http://www.bitcetera.com/page_attachments/0000/0030/regex_in_a_nutshell.pdf)

Comment: Thank Markcial but can you show full examole? If I have string in data variable like var data = "BE5555.333.333" how to check using match function?